# working on a python code from two locations

Tags: remote-access

I am working on a python code which runs all the time. But I am running it on my home machine, which is fixed. While I am at a different location, I would like to make changes / monitor the program on my home machine.

Is there a remote control / cloud service which does it? Free is preferred :)

Best regards,

RS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use log me in to get remote access Then you can open it from any computer...As it has free version that gives you free remote access.

https://secure.logmein.com/